# Use of # symbol in C

Tags: c

I'm taking on an online C language test (not for a job, just for on my own) and I keep running into questions of this type using the hash symbol. I am assuming its not a typo and I am not familiar with this use of a hash symbol.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int* func()
{
    int num = 10;
    return #
}
int main()
{
    int *ptr = func();
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the output of the above C code?

The answer is that it is a runtime error and the explanation is

> The variable defined in a function will be allocated in stack segment, which will be removed when the function returns. So accessing the address of those  variables results in segmentation fault.

Comment: That looks like a problem with the test, if you've reproduced the `return #` line accurately. The `return` is missing a return value and a semicolon.

Comment: I've never seen that. My c compiler (gnu gcc 6.4.0) shows me this error: **error: stray ‘#’ in program**

Comment: Okay, it must be a typo. This has been driving me buggy. Thanks.

Comment: The code that should be there is `return &num;`. It looks like the instructor put that into an HTML page without proper encoding. `&num;` is an HTML entity for the `#` character.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Whoever created the test didn't properly encode their HTML. What they wanted that line to look like is:

```
return &num;
```

They put that directly into the HTML of the test page, forgetting that `&XXX;` is how HTML entities are entered. `&num;` is the entity for the `#` character. They should have written:

```
return &amp;num;
```

`&amp;` is the entity for the `&` character.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting and now this all makes sense. Thanks very much.

Comment: They *should* have written C code as plain text and then used something that converts it to valid HTML.

Comment: Very nice catch! It's amazing how a tiny error like that gives you a pretty good idea of the quality of the entire site that tries to teach people programming :-)

Answer (score 0):

The function func() returns a pointer that points to the variable num. But num is an auto variable inside the function func(). It's stored in stack and its lifetime is only the lifetime of the function itself. So if you try to access that pointer in the main() it will be segmentation fault cz num doesn't exist anymore and hence pointer doesn't really point to anything.

Edit:

Hash - # is used for defining macros and header files.  return # -->  it just seems to be typo in the question. So only error is the segmentation fault due to pointer.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but it explains something OP already knows. He wants to find out what's the deal with the `#` sign, which your answer does not explain.

Comment: I felt he might be wondering about how segmentation fault occured. Anyways edited.